# Is it possible to update ngModel in real-time?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple input with an ngModel in it, the thing is that I can't see in real time what that ngModel contains and I get an error saying `Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`

```html
<input ([ngModel])="page.content" />

{{ page.content }}
```

```js
export interface Page {
  uid: string;
  content: string;
}

@Input() page: Page;

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.page.content)
}
```

So, this is what I tried and what I'm trying to do is to get a `console.log` of the things I have typed in real-time as I am typing in the `<input ([ngModel])="page.content" />`

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8sps6) for reference

Comment: first you need to store something in page as you didn't define page in `app.component.ts`. that's why it is saying content is undefined.

Comment: Maybe this `([ngModel])` should be this `[(ngModel)]`? It's *banana in a box*, not a *box in a banana*. See this: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because during the Angular lifecycle when your page is first created the value of page is null.

What you can do in your .html you could do this :

`[(ngModel)]="page?.content"`.

This checks if page exists before trying to access content.
Hope this helps!

Comment: or `{{page?.content}}` to log the value

Answer (score 2):

Please make the following change in your html:

```
[(ngModel)]="page.content"
```

instead of

```
([ngModel])="page.content"
```

and initialise the object in your ts:

```
this.page = {uid: '000001', content: 'zero'};
```

Please find the modified demo:
[modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leymzs)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize page object.
Try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.page = { uid: '1234', content: 'hello' }
}
```

or

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.page = { uid: '', content: '' }
}
```

Regards